# How to disable runasNonRoot in Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes

This is in my deployment YAML file:

```
     readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
```

What changes do I have to make to install python:

```
kubectl exec -it carts-66bc68f95f-8wjgx -c carts -n sock-shop -- sh
/usr/src/app $ apk add python
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied
/usr/src/app $ echo hello > sample.txt
sh: can't create sample.txt: Read-only file system
/usr/src/app $
```

Comment: Install python on the image before you deploy it to k8s. Both the `readOnlyRootFilesystem` and `runAsUser` prevent this from working by design.

Comment: A major point of those options so that you *can't* install anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a security context in deployment like

```
securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

Change this context to

```
securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false ----> if you want to write
```

you can access as root and write in the container

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend that you start from a container image that already has Python installed.

**By default**, you basically can't from the Kubernetes shell. This works as designed for security reasons with the default Pod `securityContext` setting `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true`. However, you can override this by using:

```
securityContext:
          ...
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          ...
```

Keep in mind that using this setting might be restricted by a [Pod Security Policy (PSP)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) already setup in your cluster.

Also, note that Pod Security Policies [are going away](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/) in Kubernetes 1.25 in favor of [PodSecurity Admission](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/2579).

Alternatively, if you are running Docker a way to bypass this is to login/SSH to the machine where this Pod is running. (You might not be able to SSH to the node depending what security controls your organization has in place)

Find the container in question:

```
$ docker ps -a | grep carts-66bc68f95f-8wjgx
```

Then exec to the container as root:

```
$ docker exec -it --user=root <container-name> bash
# apk add python
```